# jQuery to Vanilla JS, remove &nbsp;

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to transform this piece of jQuery into Vanilla JS, but I don't find any functionality to do this

```
$('p').html(function(i, html) {
  return html.replace(/&nbsp;/g, '')
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `document.querySelectorAll` method to select all the `p` tags.

```
document.querySelectorAll("p").forEach(function(el) {
    var html = el.innerHTML
    html = html.replace(/&nbsp;/g, '')
    el.innerHTML = html
})
```

Comment: True, been a while since I have actually used jQuery so a little rusty on the API

Comment: @epascarello oh I see, removing comment in 3...2...1

Answer (score 0):

Check out this website:

http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#get_html

This site is a great resource for doing what you want in "vanilla JS" instead of jQuery.

You can easily set the `innerHTML` of those elements.

```
const pTags = document.querySelectorAll('p');
for (let tag of pTags){
  tag.innerHTML = tag.innerHTML.replace(/&nbsp;/g, '')
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Matt_Morgan . The performance of the one of the verified answer seems better than this one.